# Are there still limitations to path lengths when using Windows explorer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I could not find any actual/verified information on this, regarding the "final" Release version of Windows 10.

In another question on stackexhange was this workaround with the "\?\" prefix mentioned (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath).

Does anyone know if the explorer can handle very long path names without the above workaround?

Comment: The Windows API for file access will not have changed in this respect for Windows 10. So whatever workaround/limitations documented in your link will still apply to Windows 10.

Comment: Yes; The length of a path is a fundamental design of Windows Explorer and has not changed.